# How to have chapters in classicthesis

Tags: chapters, classicthesis

I am quite new to using templates (I usually have a very simple format), and I've tried the `classicthesis` package, which I like very much. But the template I'm using doesn't use chapters, only sections, subsections etc. I would really like to use chapters because of the length of my dissertation, but I don't really know how...

Here is my header (some of it was from the template, I mostly added the things to allow writing in French):

```
% article example for classicthesis.sty
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article} % KOMA-Script article scrartcl
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
% nochapters
```

Thanks!

Comment: `article` doesn't have chapters, Change to `book` or `scrbook`: `\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}` or `\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrbook}`, and change `\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}` to `\usepackage{classicthesis}`.

Comment: You could use the template provided with classicthesis, https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/downloads, or borrow a few ideas from it. scrreprt would also be a good document class.

Answer (score 2):

The `article` document class doesn't implement a command for chapters (usually an `article` doesn't have chapters). You can switch to either `book` or the KOMA class `scrbook` and remove the `nochapters` option from `classicthesis`, i.e., change `\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}` to `\usepackage{classicthesis}`. A little complete example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,headinclude=true,footinclude]{scrbook}% or book for the standard book class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\begin{document}

\chapter{A test chapter}
\lipsum[4]
\section{A test section}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{A test subsection}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image: gonzaloClassicthesis]